# Add keys to the array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I read file (`answers.txt`) and write values into an array

```
$filename = 'answers.txt';
$file = file($filename);
```

How I can add keys to the array? `answers.txt` looks like:

```
212
150
200
212
```

I need to get keys like:

```
$array =  array (
                  "first" => "212",
                  "second" => "150",
                  "third" => "200",
                  "four" => "212"
                );
```

Comment: Try using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Is the number of the values in the file limitless, or that's just four?

Comment: Duplicate of this perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116056/php-increment-counter-function-using-words-i-e-first-second-third-etc

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for this

```
 $keys=array("first","second","third","four");

 $values=array(212,150,200,212);

 $array_combine=array_combine($keys,$values);

 print_r($array_combine);
```